# Can we make Plane Geometry with HTML element in webGL?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I want to make a plane with HTML element in webGL and can do an action like real HTML, example: make a button and when we click it, it give us an animation feedback and run the function. I already seek the answear and found `html2canvas` and `rasterizeHTML.js` but it just give like an image not natural HTML. Is there any library or any way for me to do like example above. Thanks in advance...

> NOTE : For some reason i can't use `CSS3DRenderer` in Three.js

For example image you can see in the link below:

[image]

Comment: @DacreDenny I likely want to make like in this image to render the template with HTML element [pictureLink](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sFiI5NGH1pw/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Three.js has CSS3DRenderer: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css3d#css3d_youtube

Comment: @prisoner849 yes that should the answear but for some reason i can't use CSS3DRenderer, do you have any alternative for that?

Comment: what limitation with using of this renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to define an interactive user interface with HTML that is rendered with "3D perspective".

There are a few ways this can be done - one would be to not use WebGL at all, and instead use CSS3 [transforms](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) and [perspective](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective-origin/):

```js
/* Add click handler to demonstrate that elements are still 
interactive, even when orientated in 3D space */
const button = document.getElementById("clickme");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("hi!");
});
```

```css
/* Optional - just for purpose of demonstration */
@keyframes movement {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(20deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-20deg);
  }
}

/* Define a "perspective wrapper" to give
the child elements the effect of 3D perspective */
.perspective {
  width: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.surface {
  /* Style the UI surface using regular CSS */
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;  
  
  /* Orientates the surface in 3D space */
  transform: rotateY(20deg);
  animation: movement 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
  <div class="surface">
    <button id="clickme">Click me, I'm in 3D and I'm interactive!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This approach retains the benefits of declarative HTML, the existing JavaScript DOM WebAPI, while also giving you smooth, hardware accelerated rendering of that HTML in 3D perspective.

Alternatively, if you are needing to render interactive user interfaces within a canvas element (ie, without CSS3 transforms), you could consider a library like Babylon.js which offers a pretty comprehensive [GUI framework](https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/gui).

[Here is an example show casing](https://playground.babylonjs.com/frame.html#3VMTI9#0) a fairly complex GUI rendered in 3D space, built using the Babylon.js framework - the caveat is that the GUI is defined with JavaScript (rather than HTML) however is more akin to the "Three.js way" of doing things.

Comment: Yes you got the point but this is not what i'm looking for, what i want is to implement it in 3D space area like using Three.js

Comment: @AkhdanRasiq thanks for clarifying that - in that case, you might find Babylon.js is a better choice which will allow you to build an interactive UI that is rendered in 3D space. I've extended my answer - hope that helps!

Comment: Nice... babylon.js would be the best option i have now. But i already using Three.js instead Babylon.js in my project, is there any way to do so in Three.js also?

Comment: You're welcome - I'm not aware of any GUI-like library for Three that offers what the Babylon.js GUI framework provides